# Getting "The given key was not present in the dictionary" exception when trying to create an entry

Tags: mysql, .net, nhibernate

Running a dictionary and since we did the upgrade from MySQL 8.0.28 to .29, we've been running into an "The given key was not present in the dictionary" exception and can't figure out why. Prior to the database upgrade everything appeared to be working correctly.

The UI has a commit button which allows editors to commit data to the back end, it creates a new record in one table (this part works), and then normally in another table called category - this part is now failing - DDL for the table below. Creating a record in this table manually in the database using Insert SQL it works.

Inserting new records into every other table into the system works correctly editing data in existing records works correctly.

Things we've tried:

1. A field in the table is called language and language is a reserved word in MySQL - could this be the cause of the problem?

```
-- xxxxx.category definition

CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `ID` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `agriculture` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `architecture` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `arts` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `biology` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `economy` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `education` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `environment` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `entertainment` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `food` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `geography` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `government` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `history` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IT` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `language` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `law` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `media` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `medicine` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `military` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `milling` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `music` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `names` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nationalities` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `placenames` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `printing` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `religion` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `science` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sociology` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sports` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `textiles` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `transport` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `official` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `category_allcategories_part1_idx` (`agriculture`,`architecture`,`arts`,`biology`,`economy`,`education`,`environment`,`entertainment`,`food`,`geography`,`government`,`history`,`IT`,`language`,`law`,`media`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `category_allcategories_part2_idx` (`medicine`,`military`,`milling`,`music`,`names`,`nationalities`,`placenames`,`printing`,`religion`,`science`,`sociology`,`sports`,`textiles`,`transport`,`official`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `category_placenames_idx` (`placenames`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

There aren’t any triggers defined on this table.

2 Encoding
The only collations used in our database are utf8mb4_bin, utf8mb4_general_ci and utf8mb4_bin

```
SELECT distinct(collation_name)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where
table_schema = 'xxxxx';

utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

utf8mb4_bin
utf8mb4_general_ci
```

The only character set is utf8mb4

```
SELECT distinct(character_set_name)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where
table_schema = 'xxxxx';

utf8mb4
```

The connection string specifies charset=utf8mb4 - we’ve tried adding other things like Allow User Variables=True to the connection string but this doesn’t seem to make any difference.

```
UID=xxxxx;PWD=xxxxx;DATABASE=xxxxxc;SERVER=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;charset=utf8mb4;default command timeout=120;Allow User Variables=True
```

3. Checking character sets and collations on the server,

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';

character_set_client    utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   
character_set_server    utf8mb4
character_set_system    utf8mb3
character_sets_dir  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\
```

I wasn't sure what to make of character_set_system utf8mb3?

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';

collation_connection    utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
collation_database  utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_server    utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Details:

```
.Net Framework 4.8
NHibernate 5.3.12
MySql.Data 8.0.27
```

4. We've tried MySql.Data

8.0.24 main search works - create new record fails
8.0.26 main search works - create new record fails
8.0.27 main search works - create new record fails
8.0.28 System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

DB Server:
MySQL 8.0.29 (When it was 8.0.28 everything worked well.) on Windows Server and got:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.PostAction(Object state) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\TaskContinuation.cs:line 451
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(ContextCallback callback, Object state, Task& currentTask) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\TaskContinuation.cs:line 759
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.<>c.<ThrowAsyncIfNecessary>b__18_0(Object s) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\TaskContinuation.cs:line 858
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\threadpool.cs:line 1273
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 980
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 927
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\threadpool.cs:line 1250
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\threadpool.cs:line 819
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\threadpool.cs:line 1161

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(bool)
    System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(bool)
    System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback, object)
    System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback, object)
    System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.Post(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback, object)
    System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.PostAction(object) in TaskContinuation.cs
    System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(System.Threading.ContextCallback, object, ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task) in TaskContinuation.cs
    System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.ThrowAsyncIfNecessary.AnonymousMethod__18_0(object) in TaskContinuation.cs
    System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object) in threadpool.cs
    System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, object, bool) in executioncontext.cs
    ...
    [Call Stack Truncated]
```

5. Separate transatcion
   We’ve tried placing the code where things go wrong in a separate transaction and this doesn’t help:

```
Dim myTransaction2 As ITransaction = CurrentSession.BeginTransaction

Dim myCategory As New clsCategory
myCategory.ID = Entry.ID
CurrentSession.Save(myCategory)

myTransaction2.Commit() ' things go wrong here...
```

We've noticed some people recommending not using MySql.Data at all because of a reputation for bugs and problems and recommending other libraries for connecting from NHibernate/.Net to MySQL.

Here’s the exception message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The given key was not present in the dictionary.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException() +38
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +54
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField.SetFieldEncoding() +106
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnData(MySqlField field) +352
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnsData(MySqlField[] columns) +39
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetColumns(Int32 count) +114
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.LoadColumns(Int32 numCols) +26
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet..ctor(Driver d, Int32 statementId, Int32 numCols) +60
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) +176
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() +439
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +1357
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +133
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction.Rollback() +102
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction.Dispose(Boolean disposing) +74
   NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Dispose(Boolean isDisposing) +114
   NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager.Close() +83
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Close() +317
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Dispose(Boolean isDisposing) +325
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Dispose() +375
   Dictionary.EditEntry.CreateNewRecord() in C:\Users\Will\source\repos\dictionary\dictionary\Dictionary\EditEntry.aspx.vb:1010
   Dictionary.EditEntry.GenerateWordFormTypes_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Will\source\repos\dictionary\dictionary\Dictionary\EditEntry.aspx.vb:1294
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11596288
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +274
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1890
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is a mapping for categories we use

```
<generator class="assigned"></generator>
```

in the NHibernate mapping file

```
<id name="ID">
    <generator class="assigned"></generator>
</id>
```

is the problem - if it's changed to something else - e.g.

```
<generator class="native"></generator>
```

we don't get this error.

Comment: this does change id from generated in your code to generated in the database but the table definition posted does not have autoincrement. This means that all new entities will have id==0. Maybe the id was null when the record should be saved?

Comment: A new record is created in a table which has an autoincremented primary key ("ID") then that ID is used as the ID for the new row created in the 2nd table - it's a one-to-one relationship between the two tables.

I considered a separate autoincrement in both tables but reused the ID from each new record created in the 1st table for the ID of the corresponding new record in the 2nd table to avoid any risk of the two tables becoming out of sync.

Worked MySQL 8.0.28 but in MySQL 8.0.29 creating the row in the 1st table always works but creating the row in the 2nd table always fails.

Comment: then this answer seems incorrect. category mapping must reflect, that the code assignes the id from the other table as the id and that this id should be set when inserting. so it should be `"assigned` and in code `category.Id = otherobj.Id`.